# how can i use the concat sql function in c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, datagridview

i used this statement to combine 2 column values.

```
select concat(l_name," ",f_name) as "Full Name" from students;
```

i tried this statement in dreamcoder and it worked fine but when i used this statement in my c#, it gave me an error of no method overloading. it seems that the concat() is considered a method overload when i put it in c#. is there any possible way that i could use this statement in my c#?

```
public DataTable ExecuteQuery(string cmdtext)
{
 DataTable table = new DataTable();
 var refDataAdapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(new MySqlCommand(cmdtext, CN));
 refDataAdapter.Fill(table);
 return table;
}
dataGridView1.DataSource = ExecuteQuery("select concat(l_name,", ",f_name) as FullName from students");
```

i used this code to fill show the table on my datagridview

Comment: Please mention SQL Server Version next time also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is the delimiter.  In SQL, you should be using single quotes anyway for a constant string, so you can use:

```
"select concat(l_name, ', ', f_name) as FullName from students"
```

for your query.

That would be:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ExecuteQuery("select concat(l_name, ', ', f_name) as FullName from students");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this :

```
SELECT l_name+' '+f_name AS FullName FROM [Students];
```

Its better to save query in string and pass string to **Respected Function** i.e.

```
string query = @"SELECT l_name+' '+f_name AS FullName FROM [Students]";   
dataGridView1.DataSource = ExecuteQuery(query);
```